# Value of $h$ and $k$ for system consistency

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

For what values of $h$ and $k$ is the following system consistent?

$$\begin{align} 2x_1 - 2x_2 = h\\ -6x_1 + 2x_2 = k\end{align}$$

Comment: Does my edit correspond to what you meant?

Comment: yes.... it is as is